# Http response is failing to pick up response body

Tags: java, spring, rest

When i send an application/json request using REST it returns:

```
Trace-ID=[] - Response {
  "url" : null,
  "httpMethod" : null,
  "headers" : {
    "Cache-Control" : [ "no-cache" ],
    "Pragma" : [ "no-cache" ],
    "Content-Type" : [ "application/json; charset=utf-8" ],
  },
  "body" : {
    "AccNum" : "123456789",
    "AccName" : "xxxxxx",
    "ResponseCode" : "000",
  },
  "status" : 200
}
String: "{
  "url" : null,
  "httpMethod" : null,
  "headers" : {
    "Cache-Control" : [ "no-cache" ],
    "Pragma" : [ "no-cache" ],
    "Content-Type" : [ "application/json; charset=utf-8" ],
  },
  "body" : {
    "AccNum" : "123456789",
    "AccName" : "xxxxxx",
    "ResponseCode" : "000",
  },
  "status" : 200
}"
```

The problem is i cant return just the body but i get the whole response, how do i return the body only. When i call the .getBody it still doesn't return the body but returns the whole response and how do i map the response body to to my CustomerResponse class.

My code for sending the request and receiving the response:

```
public CustomerResponse getDetails(String accNum){

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("AccSid", "123456789");
        map.put("CustAcc", accNum);
        HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map,
                headers);

        try {
            ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse> response =
                    restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request,
                            CustomerResponse.class);
            return response.getBody()

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
                if (((HttpClientErrorException) ex).getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            log.error("Error occurred while sending request for account ID {}.", accNum,
                    ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A bit difficult to see in your code but had you looked into @ResponseBody annotation ? Note that if you wish to return Json you can set it in the "produce" of our request mapping too.

Comment: @damus4 the ```@ResponseBody``` helps to show the CustomerResponse class in the response but it still missing data from the response body.
How do set the "produce" in the request mapping

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

response.getBody() actually returns the complete JSON response which you have received and not the 'body' JSON object which you want to access and return.

Now, from your code it seems that the response is of type 'CustomerResponse'. 
So I assume that the 'CustomerResponse' has an instance or static variable 'body' which can be accessed by a getter method 'getBody()'.

So finally you can try, response.getBody().getBody().

If this does not solve your problem then do share the code for 'CustomerResponse' class.